# Is there a way to halt a transaction from being confirmed until an event occurs?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, pending-transactions

For example, user 1 sends a transaction to user 2, but that transaction is not able to be confirmed until an event occurs, allowing the transaction to be confirmed and thus sent into user 2's wallet.

This would eliminate any 3rd party in the middle from the situation, making it somewhat more secure. It seems like smart contracts would be able to do this, but I am just wondering if this is possible with blockchain in general?

A good example is the bitcoin website called [Purse.io](http://purse.io). The buyer sends the bitcoin, and until the item is delivered and the buyer acknowledges that it has been, the bitcoin sits in the "escrow" and is then immediately delivered to the 2nd user's account when it has been delivered. I am asking if there is a way to do this, eliminating the 3rd party, or in Purse.io's case the "escrow".